# Все приложение только портретной ориентации и последний экран только ландшафт

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Все приложение только портретной ориентации и последний экран только ландшафт? как реализовать ландшафт(xcode)

Comment: нет еще надеюсь и жду--верного ответа нет

Comment: Из за навигейшен контроллера так и не получилось---вышел из положения создав xib файл а уже без проблем повернулся кодом:
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой ответ на stackoverflow, как раз то, что вы ищете:

[Portrait orientation in all view controllers except in modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098632/portrait-orientation-in-all-view-controllers-except-in-modal-view-controller/15102386#15102386)

Comment: спасиба с первыми контролерами прокатило--только портрет стали, а вот ландшафтным беда--когда на него переходит становиться портрет при повороте ландшафт как нада и обратно портрет не включается, а как сразу ландшафт чтоб загружался не понятно!

Comment: - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
 } ну и, видимо, попробовать модально его презентовать?

Comment: его тоже пробовал непомогает---нужен код чтобы до запуска вьюшки повернул ее!

Answer (score 1):

По моему, тока включить во всем приложении поддержку ландшавтной ориентации, и во всех контролерах где она не нужна заблокировать в делегате поворот:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
      return NO;
}
```

**UPD**
попробуйте этот метод

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Тут получится где ландшафт там и портрет будет, а нада только ландшафт!

Comment: добавил другой метод. Посмотрите доку там может еще что найдете.